# IExplorer: pop up my own dialog on save button of File Download Dilaog of IExplorer

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++

Hi I want to pop up my own dialog on save button of File Download Dilaog of IExplorer.
Can antbody suugest me how it is possible.
I am working for local application not for the web  application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting, for example, an [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(VS.85).aspx) control, I would expect you could catch and block the standard behavior by attaching to an event on the [DWebBrowserEvents2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283(VS.85).aspx). In particular, [FileDownload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768284(VS.85).aspx) would probably be a good place to start.